# Quads display differently on the two sides of an otherwise symmetrical object

Tags: modeling

I'm quite new to Blender and this doesn't make any sense to me. I tried to model a very basic "nose" by importing a cube and scaling groups of vertices in edit mode. Everything I did should have been completely symmetrical. The vertices are perfectly aligned when I look at the nose from the different flat perspectives but when I start rotating it around, one side seems to have a dent in it, while the other does not. Or rather, the triangulation in the two quads on the side is not the same, where one folds in, and the other folds out. How does this happen and how can this be corrected? Thanks.

Link to file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HLzDtOVro0CnYnGc3U3AGXDhmAk1c8Lx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure you can control how it triangulates

Comment: If you want the whole shape to be symmetrical you could use CTRL-R to put a loop down the centre, delete all the verts on one side and then add a Mirror Modifier.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. The thing is it's easy enough to mirror things with a basic shape like this but I imagine that once I make a complex head (or similar), things will get a bit tricky if I cannot control how things "fold"...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sides aren't planar, and so their shape depends on how they get triangulated.  All meshes get implicitly triangulated just before render, because our computers draw planes, and planes are defined by 3 points, not 4.  We can see how this mesh is getting triangulated by using a wireframe material:

[image]

I'm also comparing to the triangulation on a copy of the mesh with a triangulate modifier, on "shortest diagonal" mode.  You can see that this modifier creates symmetrical triangulation, so long as it's possible, because distances between symmetrical vertices are also symmetrical.

The method Blender uses for its implicit, automatic triangulation is "fixed", which uses vertex order to determine how faces get triangulated.  The reason it does this is to make triangulation work in the same way for a given face regardless of deformation (like armature deformation.)  Whatever you do, you don't want your triangulation popping when your character bends their arm!  The triangulate modifier shown here will do that if you put an armature modifier before it.

Note that using a triangulate modifier can affect the normals of the object.  Here, I've enabled "Keep normals", but that can be misleading: only custom normals are kept.  To create custom normals, I've data transferred the normals from an untriangulated copy of the mesh.

You're right to be concerned about triangulation, but what you should be doing depends on what your end goal is.  In general, you shouldn't be using faces that are so out-of-plane that you can notice their triangulation.  Whenever making a mesh for export to an engine which does not use quads, you should be thinking about triangulating it (after generating custom normals, or before generating a normal map) before export.  For rendering in Blender, there is no single right way to do things.  For example, shortest diagonal triangulation with custom normals before armature is fine, but it will affect subdivision, most likely in a way you don't want.